# converting data.table column from character to numeric seems to change uniqueness

Tags: r, data.table

I need to convert a `data.table` character column into numeric. Somehow after conversion the unique numeric values don't seem to be unique anymore. I think it might be related to large numeric values. Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
library(data.table)
options(scipen = 20)

DT = data.table(col_a = letters[1:5],
                col_b = as.character(72224192551488:72224192551492))
```

output num of entries by col_b (as expected)

```
DT[, .N, by = col_b]

            col_b N
1: 72224192551488 1
2: 72224192551489 1
3: 72224192551490 1
4: 72224192551491 1
5: 72224192551492 1
```

convert col_b to numeric

```
DT[, col_b := as.numeric(col_b)]
```

now the output looks different. I was expecting the same output though

```
DT[, .N, by = col_b]

            col_b N
1: 72224192551488 5
```

Comment: Could it be that you are hitting the maximum value for numeric data on your machine? 
`2 ^ .Machine$double.digits`
[1] https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2012-January/300250.html

Comment: I think the usual advice is to use integer64 from the bit64 package. Argh, I should have left it closed. Got confused on rereading because you changed the column type in place...

Comment: `.Machine$double.digits` = 53, should be sufficient. Actually the real problem occurs on joining different data.tables on that column later. I just broke it down to a simple case

Comment: Anyway, you might want to look at the first item under "Linked" on the left, since no one else has come by to close the question.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `summary(DT$col_b)`:

```
          Min.        1st Qu.         Median           Mean        3rd Qu.           Max. 
72220000000000 72220000000000 72220000000000 72220000000000 72220000000000 72220000000000
```

My guess is that converting it to numeric somehow rounded it off. Weird that the summary doesn't match what we can see:

```
> DT
   col_a          col_b
1:     a 72224192551488
2:     b 72224192551489
3:     c 72224192551490
4:     d 72224192551491
5:     e 72224192551492
```